# unable to load seprate file of service & directive in angular app

Tags: angularjs, file-upload

These controller, directive & service in single js file works. as the project grow for maintablity, reusability or sorting error break into different separate js file. since I am new to angular js unable to sort out the problem.please help me to sort the problem. thanks in advance.

**HTML file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>

    <title>Ticket form</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular-messages.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/service.js"></script>
    <script src="js/directive.js"></script>
    <script src="js/uploadController.js"></script>
    <script>
        var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['fileUpload','fileModel']);
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <form ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" name="form">
                <input type="file" file-model="myFile"/>
                <input type="text" ng-model="txtName">
            <button ng-click="uploadFile()">upload me</button>
    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

**Directive.js**

```
angular.module('fileModel',[]).directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;

            element.bind('change', function(){
                scope.$apply(function(){
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                });
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

**service**

```
myApp.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
    this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file,txt, uploadUrl){
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('file', file);
        fd.append("txt",txt);
        $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        })
        .success(function(d){
          console.log(d)
        })
        .error(function(){
        });
    }
}]);
```

**uploadController.js**

```
//var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope','fileUpload', function($scope, fileUpload){

    $scope.uploadFile = function(){
        var file = $scope.myFile;
        var txt = $scope.txtName;
        console.log('file is ' );
        console.dir(file);
        var uploadUrl = "/uploads";
        fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file,txt, uploadUrl);
    };

}]);
```

Error message:
[image: Error message]

Comment: Soo - what's the issue? What kind of an error are you getting?

Comment: Uncaught reference error: myApp is not defined. Isn't that clear enough? Don't use such a global variable. Or at least, if you use it, define it **before** calling methods on it.Also, you shouldn't mix angular versions: the version of angular-messages must be the same as the versin of angular. ANd you should not use minified versions during development. It makes errors much harder to read and diagnose.

Comment: Thanks , I did the things what you told. a seperate file app.js where i defined the module..#var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);#,   but only   controller file load in project .